# Django automatic add date to the form

Tags: python, django

I have models.py with a date field like this

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

View.py like this:

```
def new_topic(request):

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        form = TopicForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:topics'))
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'blog/new_topic.html', context)
```

form.py :

```
class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text', 'date_added']
        labels = {'text': ''}
```

Now problem is that i need to automatic add date to the field . To have any DB inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) in the field definition:

```
date_added = models.DateTimeField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: You might want to exclude the `date_added` field from the `TopicForm` in this case.